# Same string with different length

Tags: php, string, character-encoding, size

I don't understand why the same string has different length. I'm talking about the output 1 and 4.
Something wrong with encoding? The output 4, the string is scraped from one website.

**Code:**

```
public static function findCategoryByName($category){
    $value = "IT & Software";
    $category_1 = urlencode($value);
    $category_2 = urlencode('IT & Software');
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump("1: " . $value);
    echo '</pre>';        
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump("2: " . $category_1);
    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump("3: " . $category_2);
    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump("4: " . utf8_encode($category));
    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump("5: " . $category);
    echo '</pre>';
    return (new self)->find("name=:name", "name={$category}")->fetch();
}
```

**Output:**

```
string(16) "1: IT & Software"
string(18) "2: IT+%26+Software"
string(18) "3: IT+%26+Software"
string(20) "4: IT & Software"
string(24) "5: IT+%26amp%3B+Software"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your original post, the $category value was `IT &amp; Software` which results that outcome:

```
string(16) "1: IT & Software"
string(18) "2: IT+%26+Software"
string(18) "3: IT+%26+Software"
string(20) "4: IT &amp; Software"
string(24) "5: IT+%26amp%3B+Software"
```

It seems that you execute it in browser, try to test your code in CLI and you will see the difference.

Comment: Do u know how can i solve it? I tried utf8_decode and utf8_encode but nothing

Comment: @Juan.Queiroz wrap your $category variable in html_entity_decode before any manipulations.